# A Levy process which is not a compound Poisson drifting to $-\infty$

Tags: levy-processes

I have read a few books about L'evy processes and tried to find a concrete example such that $\{X_t\}$ is a L'evy process (but not a compound Poisson) drifting to $-\infty$ and $0$ is not regular for $(0,\infty)$. So far, all I could find are a lot of conditions. Could anyone please give me a hint or any references? Thank you very much.

Definition of a regular point: Let $X_0=0$ and $\tau=\inf\{t>0:X_t\in(0,\infty)\}$. If $P(\tau=0)=1$, then $0$ is regular for $(0,\infty)$; If $P(\tau=0)=0$, then $0$ is not regular for $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: By the first comment to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423007/what-are-the-l%c3%a9vy-processes-with-specific-increments) MO post it looks like
you are restricted to Levy processes of the form $X_t=at+\sigma B_t$ where $a<0$ and $B$ is a standard Brownian motion. Unfortunately $0$ is regular for $(0,\infty)$ because it is for BM. Now use Girsanov's theorem to conclude this for $X\,$.

Comment: Could you remind us the definition of a regular point for a Levy Process? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic. But according to Karatzas & Shreve  $0$ is a regular boundary point of  $(0,+\infty)$ if $P(\tau=0)=1$ for $\tau=\inf\{t>0:X_t\in\color{red}{(-\infty,0)}\}\,.$

Comment: Interesting. I found the above definition from the book by Kyprianou.